# Contar registros para ciertas tablas en una base - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

les comento, necesito contar todos los registros de una base en un servidor linkeado IBM en SQL Server.

De primera uso esta query para obtener todos los registros de una tabla:

```
select * from openquery(Servidor_linkeado,' select count(*) from Servidor.Eschema.Tabla')
```

El asunto es que necesito hacer lo mismo, pero para todas las tablas que comienzan con CRM01_ (Ejemplo CRM01_Empleados), ya que necesito hacer una comparacion de registros para esas tablas con respecto a otro servidor.

Desde el otro servidor no tengo problemas, ya que es uno local y ejecuto esta query para obtener los registros:

```
SELECT
    sysobjects.Name
    , sysindexes.Rows
FROM
    sysobjects
    INNER JOIN sysindexes
    ON sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
WHERE
    type = 'U'
    AND sysindexes.IndId < 2
ORDER BY
    sysobjects.Name
```

Espero me puedan ayudar y de antemano gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, encontre esta query andando por ahí, no soy experto en sql server pero espero te sirva

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [SchemaName],
[Tables].name AS [TableName],
SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
AND [Partitions].index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
-- WHERE [Tables].name = N'name of the table'
GROUP BY SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), [Tables].name;
```

Cuando ejecutes esta consulta, obtendrás el siguiente resultado

[image: output]

Comment: Todo se debe hacer directamente en SQL Server, desde el Management Studio, no a traves de un programa, por ello necesito una query que, de primera, me entregue el total de los registros de las tablas para lo mencionado en mi mensaje